# jQuery rebinding or a live event on a new element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, timepicker

I am using this [timepicker](http://labs.perifer.se/timedatepicker/) which works great but the problem is I am adding the input fields on the fly and the time picker is not working on newly created input tags

I am using this jQuery

```
    $('.timepicker').timePicker({
      startTime: "02.00",  // Using string. Can take string or Date object.
      endTime: new Date(0, 0, 0, 15, 30, 0),  // Using Date object.
      show24Hours: false,
      separator:'.',
      step: 15
    });
```

I am having someone click a button and a new input field with the class time picker is getting appended to the page but the the jQuery time picker is not working...any ideas how to bind...

I tried this

```
    $('.timepicker').bind('click', function(){
        $('.timepicker').timePicker({
          startTime: "02.00",  // Using string. Can take string or Date object.
          endTime: new Date(0, 0, 0, 15, 30, 0),  // Using Date object.
          show24Hours: false,
          separator:'.',
          step: 15
        });
    });
```

But didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use live -

```
$('.timepicker').live('click', function(){
    $(this).timePicker({
      startTime: "02.00",  // Using string. Can take string or Date object.
      endTime: new Date(0, 0, 0, 15, 30, 0),  // Using Date object.
      show24Hours: false,
      separator:'.',
      step: 15
    }).focus();
    $(this).removeClass('timepicker');
});
```

Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/Spfpj/4/

Comment: This would reapply the timepicker plugin on every click. A better approach would be to apply the plugin when adding the new element to the DOM.

Comment: yup. handling the addition of dom can be one option. Or you can simply remove the class. Updated the answer with the latter.